# Odoo New API Auto Increment/Sequencing

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

So I've been looking around the web, on a mission to find a way to create my own sequence for the new API for Odoo 9 that I am using. However, I wasn't able to find a satisfactory answer. As far as I've seen, sequences aren't very well documented in the Odoo Docs.

Here's what I know so far.

From [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-implement-sequences-8830) I know:

```
<openerp>
  <data noupdate="1">
    <record model="ir.sequence.type" id="seq_type_obj_id">
      <field name="name">obj_id_seq</field>
      <field name="code">seq.obj.name</field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.sequence" id="seq_obj_id">
      <field name="name">obj_id_seq</field>
      <field name="code">seq.obj.name</field>
      <field name="prefix">prefix</field>
      <field name="padding">3</field>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

**But apparently ir.sequence.type is NOT a model that exists and I cannot use, so I removed that record and it compiles/updates without errors.**

From previous source, I also know:

```
my_sequence = self.pool['ir.sequence'].get(cr, uid, seq_obj_name)
self.write(cr, uid, [picking.id], {'ur_emp_no_field': my_sequence})
```

But this is the old API, so I've changed it to:

```
# Correct me if I'm wrong here
my_sequence = self.env['ir.sequence'].get('seq.obj.name')
```

And have added it to the create function, which then writes to an arbitrary field to be stored.

So I've done all this without getting any error messages.

**My problem is:** The field I'm storing the sequence instance to is not changing. I checked in the sequence settings and the sequence is not being incremented when I create a new record either.

For the sake of clarity:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    for rec in self:
        rec.seq_id = self.env['ir.sequence'].get('seq.obj.name')
    return super(PurchaseOrder, self).create(vals)
```

If someone could give me a thorough explanation of where Odoo does the auto increment, maybe direct me to a proper source, or point out what is wrong with my code and how to fix it, I would much appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code didn't update the directory variable. That's the reason of it.

Try with this code.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals:
        vals.update({
            'seq_id': self.env['ir.sequence'].get('seq.obj.name')
        })
    return super(PurchaseOrder, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. I suppose assigning variables directly when I overwrite the create function wasn't exactly a good idea.